# Mojo::Log - Is it possible to add the line number to the messages?

Tags: perl, logging, line-numbers, mojolicious

Is it possible to configure [Mojo::Log](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Mojo%3A%3ALog) in a way so it adds the line number to the log messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. That is not a supported feature.

Answer (score 5):

Doesn't look like it, but you can use a [special literal](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Special-Literals) in there yourself:

```
$log->debug(__LINE__ . ': Some debug message.');
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use Mojo::Log? If you can use MojoX::Log::Log4perl, you're home free.

```
use MojoX::Log::Log4perl;

sub startup {
    ...
    my $logconfig =<<EOF;
    ...
    log4perl.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern = [%d] %P %p %C,%L - %m%n
    ...
EOF

    my $mojox_logger = MojoX::Log::Log4perl->new( \$logconfig );
    $self->log($mojox_logger);
}
```

The %L in the ConversionPattern is for the line number.